# SetParent no longer works?

Tags: c#

This was the code I used to change the parent of a process:

```
Process p = new Process("calc.exercise");
SetParent(p.MainWindowHandle, this.Handle);
```

It just stopped working. Did they have an update that changed it or could there be something else wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line just creates a process instance:

```
Process p = new Process("calc.exercise");
```

It never started it. And thus `p.MainWindowHandle` isn't going to have a valid value.

You either need to start the process by calling `Start` method; or if you need to get the instance of an already-running process, use `Process.GetProcessByName` method.

If you have started the `Process` and still it doesn't work -- it could be that the `MainWindowHandle` property isn't updated. This could happen for several reasons. You need to give it some time.

For example:

```
int tries = 0;
while(p.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero && tries <3)
{
    tries++;
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
SetParent(p.MainWindowHandle, this.Handle);
```

Comment: Sorry i do have the start instead of the send process and the exe auto corrected to exercise on my phone

Comment: @Austin You mean you started the process and still it doesn't work?

Comment: Yes it's started, I haven't changed the code in about 2 weeks it just doesn't work anymore

Comment: @Austin Usually `MainWindowHandle` property will not return correct value immediately, you need to give it some time. Refer my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You haven't [`Start`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8zac0ca(v=vs.110).aspx)-ed your process yet.